# ReferenceError: jest is not defined when trying to run tests inside a lib in a nx monorepo

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I've been trying to run tests inside a lib from a NX monorepo and it's not working. First it's wasn't finding the types, so I added `/// <reference types="@types/jest" />` and It was solved. Then when I ran the test and I got the error: **ReferenceError: jest is not defined**. Jest is installed in the root of the monorepo, I also tried to install jest for the lib, also dropped the node_modules. Nothing worked for me.

```js
/// <reference types="@types/jest" />

import { handleTokenAuthorization } from '.';

describe('auth funtions', () => {
  it('Should mount and replace url correctly to login screen', () => {
    const url = `${process.env.NX_APP_CLIENT_ID}/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${process.env.NX_FRONT_URL}&scope=openid+profile&redirect_uri=${process.env.VITE_FRONT_URL}/receive-auth-token`;
    const replaceFn = jest.spyOn(window.location, 'replace');

    handleTokenAuthorization();

    expect(replaceFn).toBeCalledWith(url);
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched vitest by @nrwl/jest:jest, so I added the following config inside the project.json from my lib and the test runner worked fine.

```js
"test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": [
        "{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "libs/util/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true,
        "coverageDirectory": "coverage/libs/util"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "ci": true,
          "codeCoverage": true
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: vitest and jest are two different testing libraries (with very similar api's). The above configuration shows jest only